# style tag is ignored by uiwebview

Tags: ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to give my html an css inline style. But this style gets ignored.

This is the HTML string that I'm using for         webView.loadHTMLString(htmlBelow, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)

let fontsize = 16 //This is an dynamic variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">
        <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\"content=\"ie=edge\">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            ​html {
                font-size:\(fontsize)px; */THIS DOESN'T WORK/*
            }
        </style>
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\style.css\">
        <script src=\"jquery-3.4.1.min.js\"></script>
        <script src=\"script.js\"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=\ "sqr-tree-level\"> \(restOfHtml) </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to set the fontsize dynamically.
When I change the font-size in my css file it works, but I want to set it dynamically. That's why I wanna do it like this.

[This is how my document.head.innerHTML looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKgPk.png)

Comment: How are you building this html data? - right now this doesn't look like it would compile?

Comment: I'm doing it like this: 
let fullHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"en\"> <head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"> <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"ie=edge\"> <title>Document</title> <style>​body {color:blue!important;}​</style> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\(Constants.cssStylingFile)\"> <script src=\"jquery-3.4.1.min.js\"></script> <script src=\"script.js\"></script> </head> <body> <div class=\"sqr-tree-level\">   \(restOfHtml)     </div> </body> </html>" It fully works except the part of the <style></style>

Comment: What does the resulting html look like? - is the `fontsize` variable injected correctly?

Comment: yeah it is injected correctly, it looks like this: <style>
            ​html {
                font-size:23px;
            }
        </style>

Comment: And you deffo removed any overriding `font-size` css in your stylesheet?

Comment: I override it on 1 place, but if I remove this it still doesn't work

Comment: have you tried changing other elements instead like `body { }` or `p { }` ?

Comment: I also tried `body {  } `, that also doesn't work

Comment: But it works when I directly set it in my style.css, but then I don't have it dynamically

Comment: how about inline? `<body style=\"font-size:\(fontsize)px;\">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference the fix here was to put the styling in to the `<body>` tag instead of in the head `<style>` tag.

`<body style=\"font-size:\(fontsize)px;\">`